# How to position text element based on text characters using ngStyle?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I am running angular, precisely angular 6. I calculated the number of characters of given text element shown in the box.Based on this value I want to position element that is marked in red. I want to do this because number of charters is not constant, when the character length exceeds html element goes out of screen.

What I have tried is applied inline style through ngStyle.

But this didn't work

```
  <p id="spandiv" [ngStyle]="{'position':'relative','right':'var(customerLength)px','background-color':'red'}">{{customerName}}</p>
```

inside typescript I calculate the character and assign it to variable customerLength.

```
   let stringValue = customer.AccountID+'('+customer.AccountName+')';
   this.customerLength = stringValue.length;
```

My question is , how to position html element using the value I get from typescript?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `'right':customerLength + 'px'`

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-51gyfz?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

```
<p id="spandiv" [ngStyle]="{'position':'relative','right':customerLength + 'px','background-color':'red'}">{{customerName}}</p>
```